# MySql transaction with third party code

Tags: mysql, transactions

I am running into a problem where I want to run a piece of third party code in a MySql transaction and revert both back if any of them fails in the process. What is the standard way to do this? Thanks

sample code would be:

```
...
some mysql code
some third party code
rollback both if either mysql commits fails or the third part fails
...
```

Comment: You are not giving enough information. Some code may help understand your issue.

Comment: Click "edit" to change the text of your question.